# Ссылка на почту

Tags: html

Как можно сделать ссылку на почту, что б при нажатии на нее, открывалась страница почты, а имеено на страницу "написать /отправить письмо",  и в строку "кому" передавалась заданая строка(мыло получателя).
Знаю, есть mailto, но открывает встроенную прогу (outloock), но это совсем не то

Comment: mailto — это именно то, что вам нужно. Вместо Outlook можно повесить на него почтовый сайт, и это должен настроить сам пользователь в настройках своего браузера, это не ваша проблема https://i.stack.imgur.com/rX3At.png